# How to send image file from form to mongoDB using flask and pymongo

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo, html-formhandler

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from pymongo import MongoClient
from PIL import Image
import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.data

todos = db.images


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        imagedata = request.files["file"]
        
        image_bytes = io.BytesIO()
        imagedata.save(image_bytes, format="JPEG")
        image = {
            image: image_bytes.getvalue()
        }
        todos.insert_one(image)
        return redirect(url_for("home"))

    return render_template("index1.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fooiO.png)

I am trying to store image file in mongoDB using flask and pymongo but i don't understand what was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your issue right here is that you're using the `save()` [method](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.save.html#werkzeug.FileStorage.save) of a `FileStorage` object.

So, removing the line `imagedata.save(image_bytes, format="JPEG")` would help.

Then if your image is more than 16MB, be aware that MongoDB will hit a [limitation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) here.